# Assign value from array to a variable outside its constructor in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get variables in my view structure which will be updated from Firestore every time the user submits a rating so that a new currentRating can be determined. (currentRating is the average of all currentRatings, but I'm not storing individual ratings - I'm just trying to have my currentRating for each of the schools keep being updated after each new rating). I have created the class, FireStoreManager which creates an array which should be reading data to an array. The base of my array is from my identifiable structure RatingSubmission. I then have the first part of my final view structure where I've referenced FirestoreManager() because I'm trying to then be able to reference the different items in the array, Rating Submission, but I keep getting errors.

```
class FirestoreManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ratingSubmission = [RatingSubmission]()
    var currentRating: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    func fetchRatingSubmission() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let docRef = db.collection("RatingInformation").document()
        
        docRef.getDocument{(document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ??
                "nil"
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                
                let data = document.data()
                
                self.currentRating = data!["RatingInformation"]! as! CGFloat
                print("after update: \(self.currentRating)")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        fetchRatingSubmission()
    }
}
```

```
 struct RatingSubmission: Identifiable {
     var id: String = UUID().uuidString
     var location: String
     var currentRating: Float
     var usualRating: Float
     var totalRatings: Float
 }
```

```
struct NewRatingView: View {
    var model = FirestoreManager()
    var schools = ["North Avenue", "West Village", "Brittain"]
    @State private var location = "West Village"
    var currentRating: CGFloat {
       didSet {
           model.fetchRatingSubmission(currentRating)
       }
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you get? One issue you will find in that it is not possible for a `@Puiblished` variable to detect changes inside the objects of an array - it detects only changes in the collection. You might want to have your `RatingSubmission` object as a Core Data entity: these entities always publish their changes, keeping your UI up to date when you call them as `ObservableObject`s.

Comment: When I print 'print(model.$ratingSubmission) which I should think would print the array in the console, I get this: Publisher(subject: Combine.PublishedSubject<Swift.Array<Real_Time_Reviews_App.RatingSubmission>>). How would I get this so that it shows me an array so that if I assign it to a variable in my view structure I could then pull variables via index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: you can iterate over the array in your view by calling `model. ratingSubmission` in the `body`. But the elements won't update automatically from Firestore.

Comment: Would there be a way then for me to have variables which are updated from Firestore before being used in a function?